# Sympy IndexedBase substitution

Tags: sympy

I am a bit confused how to use [`Indexed objects`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/indexed.html#module-sympy.tensor.indexed) in Sympy. Suppose I have the following setup:

```
from sympy import *
x = IndexedBase('x')
i = Idx('i')
s = Sum(x[i], (i, 0, 5))
s
```

Output:

```
  5       
 ___      
 ╲        
  ╲       
  ╱   x[i]
 ╱        
 ‾‾‾      
i = 0
```

Which ofcourse is equal to

```
x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5]
```

By doing `s.doit()`. Now, how do I substitute `x` with some range? I expected the following to work:

```
s.subs(x, list(range(6)))
```

But it does not do anything it would seem. However `s.doit().subs(x[0], 0)` works, but it will only substitute 1 element. Is it not intended to substitute `IndexedBase` with some list?

Answer (score 0):

When using SymPy, there is one thing to always keep in mind: the only objects SymPy operates on is SymPy's object. Consider this example:

```py
expr = x + 3
r = expr.subs(x, 2)
print(r, type(r))
5 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Integer'>
```

Here, we passed a `int` number to `subs`, but SymPy internally converted it to an `Integer` number. Then, it performed the addition, producing the `Integer` number 5.

There are occasions in which the input parameter cannot be converted to something SymPy can understand. Your example is one such occasion. Let's use `sympify` (or its alias `S`) to verify how your list is going to be converted to a SymPy object:

```py
l = list(range(6))
c = sympify(l)
type(c)
# out: list
```

As we can see, SymPy is unable to convert an object of type `list`, hence it is unable to use it. In short, this is the reason your code doesn't produce the correct output.

However, let's try the same trick with a `tuple`:

```py
c = sympify(tuple(l))
type(c)
# out: Tuple
```

Here, SymPy converted a Python object of type `tuple` to a SymPy object of type `Tuple`. Now, the substitution should produce the correct result:

```
s.doit().subs(x, tuple(l))
# out: 15
```

Here are the most common SymPy objects the support iteration: `Tuple`, `Matrix`, `Array`.